# System.debug() not appearing in batch test

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, debugging

I am running a test on a batchable class.

```
@isTest

public class BatchSkillExcalationUpdaterTest {
    static testMethod void ValidateUpdates() {

        ...
        EscalationSkillUpdater SkillBatch = new EscalationSkillUpdater();    
        system.debug(logginglevel.FINEST, 'BATCHING...');
        Database.executeBatch(SkillBatch);
        system.debug(logginglevel.FINEST, 'FINISHED BATCHING.');
        ...
    }
}
```

The class I am testing:

```
global class EscalationSkillUpdater implements Database.Batchable <sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        ...        
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, list<SkillEscalationChangeRecord__c> Data) {
        ...
        System.debug(logginglevel.FINEST, 'FLAG');
        update Data;
    }

    global void finish (Database.BatchableContext BC) {}
}
```

However, the Debug message in the `execute()` method is not showing up:

[image]

The `'FLAG'` from the batchable class is not showing up.  Why is this?  Is there another way to "print" values to examine?

Comment: Are you sure the query is returning results? If there are no records returned then the execute method will NOT well execute

Comment: I'm not sure the query is returning result, that actually what I'm trying to debug.  I'm getting the same issue even when the `System.debug()` is the first line in the `start()` method.

Comment: remember in test methods you have to created the appropriate data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `Test.startTest();` before calling `Database.executeBatch(SkillBatch);`. Then call `Test.stopTest();` afterwards to have the actual batch run.

From [Adding a Test for the Batch Apex Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_batch_2.htm):

> The call to `Database.executeBatch` is included within the `Test.startTest` and `Test.stopTest` block. This is necessary for the batch job to run in a test method. The job executes after the call to `Test.stopTest`. Any asynchronous code included within `Test.startTest` and `Test.stopTest` gets executed synchronously after `Test.stopTest`.

So, without the start/stop calls your batch job will be queued, but will never run in the testing context as it is typically asynchronous.

Also, as Eric commented, ensure that you have inserted SkillEscalationChangeRecord__c records as part of the test for the batch query to find.

Comment: This seems to be the problem.  I was calling `test.starttest()` before inserting my test objects and `stoptest()` after my assertions.  Moving these to contain only the `database.executeBatch()` call, and it is not printing debug successfully.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The most logical answer:

The query in the start method is not returning results thus the execute method will NOT well execute and no debug will be shown there

or

To daniel's point below (I believe he will turn out to be having the correct answer)

You have to wrap the batch call in `Test.StartTest` and `test.stopTest`

(I forgot you posted your test class....)